# Java get element from list of list

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have a list like this :

`List<List<String>> myList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();`

that I fill with other lists :

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
String val1;
String val2; 
val1 = "java";
val2 = "c++";
lst.add(val1);
lst.add(val2);
myList.add(lst);

List<String> lst2 = new ArrayList<String>();
val1 = "pizza";
val2 = "fruit";
lst.add(val1);
lst.add(val2);
myList.add(lst);
```

I want to get the elements of the list by giving index  something like :

```
String valeur = myList[0].val1 ;
String valeur2 = myList[1].val2 ;
```

which of course is a wrong way; I don't know how to do this;
I read something about closures but I don't know what is it .. 
any help will be apprecdiated , and I hope my question is clear
don't hesitate to correct or ask me if something is wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: `myList.get(0).get(0);`.  If you want to access the values by name, then you will need to use a `Map`.  See [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer really a quick answer , I'm going to try this now.

Comment: I see there is already an answer. But replace also the declaration with:
`List<List<String>> myList = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: @LowLevel While I don't disagree, it won't make a difference to the OP's problem, but will mean they can type less, so you might use *"You can also use..."*, just in case the OP sees it as a requirement to solve there problem ;)

Comment: @LowLevel please explain to me why this declaration is more good than what I did . If you don't mind

Comment: @MadProgrammer  is there a way to make vote to people who comments here? I mean when someone answers the question in a comment .. I'm new in this site so I don't know how to do it.

Comment: It's just a step forward. If you write the same thing two times in your code you kind-of try to make sure the robot has understood you. It's the same like writing: `int i = 0; i = 0;`

Comment: @Potato That will have any effect, but up-voting comments is away to highlight agreement with the statement

Comment: @MadProgrammer don't repeat yourself: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=79394

Comment: @LowLevel My point is, your recommendation won't make a difference to the problem the OP is having, do I disagree with your recommendation, no, I just thing letting the OP know that it is a general recommendation and not something that will effect the general outcome of there current issue is worth highlighting, otherwise you're focusing the attention of the OP onto something that isn't going to immediately help them solve their issue

Comment: @Mad I've already understood what your point is. You don't have to repeat it. Even if you didn't tell me your point I knew it; I'm not a robot.

Comment: I didn't even criticize the so-called "OP". I do not understand your panic and frustration.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`List#get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int))

> Returns the element at the specified position in this list.

```
String valeur = myList.get(index).get(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
String valeur = myList.get(0).get(0)

Comment: How does this answer improve the other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34257681/18980756)?